# Fix image size in carousel using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to make an image carousel stay the same size for each and every picture no matter what the picture.  Currently, it always changes sizes and I can't figure out the reason.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Image Caurosel -->
      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
            <!-- Slider -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span9" id="slider">
                    <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span2" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                            <!-- Carousel items -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0"><img id="pic1"     src="{% static 'images/pic01.jpg' %}" class="img-thumbnail" height="300" width="300"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="1"><img id="pic2" src="{% static 'images/pic01.jpg' %}" class="img-thumbnail" height="300" width="300"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="2"><img id="pic3" src="{% static 'images/pic01.jpg' %}" class="img-thumbnail" height="300" width="300"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="3"><img id="pic4" src="{% static 'images/pic01.jpg' %}" class="img-thumbnail" height="300" width="300"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="4"><img id="pic5" src="{% static 'images/pic01.jpg' %}" class="img-thumbnail" height="300" width="300"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                      <!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <div class="carousel-controls-mini">
                            <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                            <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                        </div>          
                      </div> 
                  </div>
                  </div>  
         </div>
        </div>
<!-- Image Caurosel -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel-inner img {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}

#myCarousel {
   font-size:90%;
}

.carousel-controls-mini {

}

.carousel-controls-mini > a {
   border:1px solid #eee;
    width:20px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
            var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length-1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
```

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` onto the end of your css width and height, like this:

```
.carousel-inner img {
    width:250px !important;
    height:250px !important;
}
```

Comment: tried this, no dice. thanks man. even tried this with changing item as @willjleong suggested and still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a pseudo cropper and decide if you are willing to cut the sides of the images or the top and bottom.  Each outer div of class='item' (but I would probably create a new class called .image-crop) needs the wanted image dimentions. Then the actuall image will just have width:100% if you don't want the width cropped, or height:100% if you don't want the height cropped. The overflow: hidden create the cropping hack.

CSS with height cropping:

```
.item { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 250px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%
}
```